# Google Map api v2 - setUpMap() causes errors

Tags: android, google-maps

What is wrong with my code? I am doing a map/location app. Showing the map is ok but trying to add setUpMap() method/function causes the app to stop.

main_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Activity:

package tri.mylocapp;

```
//import...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{ 

    GoogleMap googlemap = null;
    LatLng latlng;
    LocationManager lm;
    String provider;
    Location location;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (isGooglePlay()){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMap();
        }

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlay(){
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Log.d("mytag", "google ok");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            Log.d("mytag","google not ok");
            Toast.makeText(this, "GooglePlay is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setUpMap(){
        if (googlemap == null){
            Log.d("mytag", "googlemap is null, making it available");
            googlemap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googlemap != null){
                Log.d("mytag", "googlemap is not null");
                googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

                if (provider == null){
                    onProviderDisabled(provider);
                }
                location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

LogCat (Errors and mytag):

```
04-06 12:54:13.099: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.099: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 4 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255980 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 206828 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 157676 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:13.103: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 108524 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:54:13.255: E/Trace(1750): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-06 12:54:20.723: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:20.723: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:20.723: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:20.723: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:54:37.215: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:37.215: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:37.215: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:37.215: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:54:39.579: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:39.579: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:39.579: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:39.579: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:54:39.599: E/Trace(1769): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-06 12:54:39.607: E/jdwp(1769): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-06 12:54:41.403: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:41.403: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:41.403: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:41.403: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:54:41.679: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(531): Could not find a dictionary pack
04-06 12:54:41.679: E/ActivityThread(531): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
04-06 12:54:41.711: E/dalvikvm(1633): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method box.a
04-06 12:54:43.767: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:43.767: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:43.767: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:54:43.767: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:55:57.495: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.495: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.499: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.499: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 12:55:57.531: E/Trace(1841): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tri.mylocapp/tri.mylocapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at tri.mylocapp.MainActivity.setUpMap(MainActivity.java:61)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at tri.mylocapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-06 12:55:57.827: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     ... 11 more
04-06 12:55:57.859: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.859: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.859: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.859: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 12:55:57.859: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 206832 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.315: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.315: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.315: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.315: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
04-06 13:13:01.363: E/Trace(1874): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-06 13:13:01.375: E/jdwp(1874): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tri.mylocapp/tri.mylocapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at tri.mylocapp.MainActivity.setUpMap(MainActivity.java:61)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at tri.mylocapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-06 13:13:01.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     ... 11 more
04-06 13:13:01.671: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.671: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.671: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.671: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 49152 
04-06 13:13:01.671: E/SocketStream(342): readFully was waiting for 206832 bytes, got 49152
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize the googlemap object to null before you try to compare its value to anything.

ie.

```
private void setUpMap(){
        if (googlemap == null){ //in your code googlemap var is uninitialized at this point
        ...}}
```

try changing the line:

```
GoogleMap googlemap;
```

to

```
GoogleMap googlemap = null;
```

Oh, and by the way; I just wanted to say thanks for including your debug information. I've been browsing around some of these android questions on here, and I keep seeing situations where people include code; but not error information. In my mind that is realistically equivalent to going to a mechanic shop and asking the mechanic why your car is driving funny, and when they ask to go outside and see it; you tell them its in your garage at home....

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. But the app still stop. It seems you're right because the fixed code generates more errors, I think the fixed code fixes the current error and when the app goes to next steps, it again encounters errors. Could you help me fix more errors. I don't have much experience in reading logcat.

Comment: I discovered the cause and fixed it. I din't not initialize lm (locattion manager). Now everything is ok, adding marker is also ok.  I will move to next step: finding direction of two location. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tri Quoc Nguyen Good problem solving!